# tomcat shows 404 error in html but jsp work fine

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA to create a simple WebApplication with tomcat 7.0.64.

I run the tomcat in IDEA then http://localhost:8080/ would working fine, showing the index.jsp.And then i can append xxx.jsp to turn to that page.
but if i want to turn to a .html page, it would be a 404 error :[image: 404 error]

the .html file would work fine and show things if i open it in browser.

after i changed the name of index.jsp(so index.html would be the gate i guess), the question still remains.

my folder hierarchy ：
[image: project folders]

#### EDIT:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


</web-app>
```

Actually nothing in there because project generate nothing and i do not know what attributes should be config.

Comment: Show us your `web.xml` file.  The request for `index.html` is most likely being intercepted.

Comment: you are not giving the right url to lunch that html file try something like  http://localhost:8080/html/index.html or run the file directly from intellij

Comment: @PacMan Uh...its weird.I had did this before asking and at that time i cant visit localhost:8080/html/index.html , but now it seem like worked.Thanks anyway!

Comment: @PacMan Now i m not sure is the index.html open in tomcat or not. How can i make the gate of tomcat be the index.html(just like index.jsp before) so i can run tomcat and it shows.

Comment: did you check tomcat logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's all simple , you can configure it in your web.xml file by adding these tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>name you want to see</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>html/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and then the index.html will be loaded as the first page while running your application

Comment: this is easy to understand, but maybe for some other reasons it shows 404 ,...Uh...and now , some how, it can show index.html in localhost:8080 BUT no style! console show that cant GET css and img and even cant use '$' symbol!

Comment: @matsuiCao try  to load only some css file instead of that html and see if it will be opened having content or not

Comment: now I set index.jsp jump to .html directly which i want by response.sendRedirect("html/index.html"); and everything wok fine.Thank you very much : )

Comment: @matsuiCao glat cause it help :) you can check my answer as the right one

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've stored the project in the right location and that the port 8080 is where Tomcat runs the server. Assuming you have, the way you're calling index.html, Tomcat is looking in its default folder for a file called index.html. It isn't looking in its subdirectories for that file. You can see why because if you have multiple projects and each with its own index.html then it would not know which one to display.

You need to tell your browser which folder/project to look in. If your project is 'MyProject', type into your browser **localhost:8080/MyProject/index.html**.

Essentially you've created a local server and you're looking at the files that the server has. It's' the same as when you try to look at the files you have through your terminal. You are giving the browser a path to the file so you need to specify the project/folder name.

Answer (score -1):

Your path maybe incorrect or your tomcat pirated.Um,maybe the former more likely.